# Google Ads API tells me Account inactive

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I've created MCC Test account, and I got a developer token which still need to be approved.
But this should be no problem as cited by google:

> ... You don't need to wait for your
>   developer token to be approved before using it with a test account.

So why I'm getting this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: [QuotaCheckError.ACCOUNT_INACTIVE @ ; trigger:'&lt;null&gt;']
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201406}ApiExceptionFault:<message>[QuotaCheckError.ACCOUNT_INACTIVE @ ; trigger:'&lt;null&gt;']</message><ApplicationException.Type>ApiException</ApplicationException.Type><errors xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="QuotaCheckError"><fieldPath/><trigger>&lt;null&gt;</trigger><errorString>QuotaCheckError.ACCOUNT_INACTIVE</errorString><ApiError.Type>QuotaCheckError</ApiError.Type><reason>ACCOUNT_INACTIVE</reason></errors>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is encountering the same problem.
This has mostly to do with the developer token of MCC-Test account.

You have to use a **developer token of a non-test MCC Account.**

That's all.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, I'm in trouble with creating a test account now , could you please give me some advice?